# A way to shorten declaration

Tags: c++, templates

I have something like this:

```
 template<class Key,
                 class Value,
                 class Compare_p = Compare<ByKey>,
                 template<class,class> class Insert_p = NoOverride,
                 template<class> class FailureSignal_p = ThrowOnFailure,
                 class AllocFactor_p = AllocFactorScientific<>,
                 class Alloc = Allocator<FailureSignal_p>
                >
        class Map : private Map_Base<Implementation> //Implementation is a Link with identical  
//params to Map
        {
        public:  
//I've tried to use typedef here but it's too late
            typedef LinkImplementation<Pair<Key,Value>,Compare_p,Insert_p,FailureSignal_p,AllocFactor_p,Alloc> Implementation;
    };
```

So the big Q is: is there a way to make this declaration (of LinkImplementation<>) shortened?

Answer (score 1):

maybe create a template "struct" for map parameters like this:

```
template <class Key, ...  blablabla > 
struct MapParams{
typedef Key key_t;
typedef Value value_t;
..................
};
```

then use this "struct" as a single template parameter
for both Map and Map_Base templates?

Comment: Wouldn't this mean that the users suffer? `Map<Foo, Bar> x` vs `Map<MapParams<Foo, Bar> > x`?